# Why does Ubuntu keep asking me for another super user's password?

Tags: password, users, authentication, administrator

I have two users:

- `misha-local` (the first user I created when installing Ubuntu)
- `misha` (a user authenticated against an LDAP server)

I'm logged in as `misha`.

```
misha@misha-antec:~$ whoami
misha
misha@misha-antec:~$ groups
lmd adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

As you can see, `misha` is an admin user. However, when I do anything requiring superuser access in the GUI (like installing software), I get this:

[image: password prompt for misha-local]

Why is it asking me for the password for `misha-local`? The current user also has administrative privileges. Why doesn't it ask for the current user's password instead?

**EDIT**

This is an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop installation.

Some more relevant command-line output:

```
misha@misha-antec:~$ id misha
uid=13009(misha) gid=10000(lmd) groups=10000(lmd)
misha@misha-antec:~$ id misha-local
uid=1000(misha-local) gid=1000(misha-local) groups=4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare),1000(misha-local)

misha@misha-antec:~$ whoami
misha
misha@misha-antec:~$ groups
lmd adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
misha@misha-antec:~$ groups misha
misha : lmd
```

This is odd. `groups` is reporting that `misha` **is** part of `sudo` and `adm`, but `id` and `groups misha` reports the opposite. What's going on?

**EDIT 2**

```
misha@misha-antec:~$ id -run
misha
misha@misha-antec:~$ id -un
misha
misha@misha-antec:~$ ps -A | grep nscd
8622 ?        00:00:02 nscd
```

Comment: Could you share the result of doing `id misha` and `id misha-local` at a terminal ?

Comment: @Benoit: sure, please see the updated question.

Comment: Could you do know `id -run` than `id -un`. I suspect that even if you log in with *misha*, your effective id is *misha-local*. It may be related to the configuration against the LDAP server to get the user.

Comment: Another idea, just out of my head now, do you have the **nscd** process running or anyother caching mechanism enabled for your LDAP usernames and groups resolution ?

Comment: @Benoit: thanks for your ideas. I've updated the question. Yes, nscd is running.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the user **misha** to the *sudo group*

Add a user to the sudo group:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

The change will take effect the next time the user logs in.

Comment: `misha` is already in the `sudo` group - please see the original question.

Comment: the command `groups` shows what groups there are please run `groups <username>` to see if misha is part of the sudo groups

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the updated question.

Comment: when you type the command `groups` as per your output it shows what groups are available on the PC. when you type `groups misha` it should give you what groups the user misha is in and from your output of `id misha` it says that you are not part of sudo groups

Comment: @StallionSA: **groups** used without username in parameters report the groups appartenance for the current user running the command, not the available groups on the system.

Answer (score -1):

The user you are now is known as Administrator, he is granted most of permissions but not all. Linux system based on root(super user) parodigm: root can do anything without some feedbacks like asking password. In Ubuntu root user was turned off.
So Administrator has to perform this feedbacks sometimes, but if you dont want this you can always do sudo | sudo -i | gksudo | ... to grant yourself or your application rigths of root to do everything. Ones you do sudo it will, of course, ask you a password but than app will run with root privileges.

Comment: You might have misread the question...

Comment: It is not about the password being asked, but being asked to the (at least seemingly) wrong user.

Comment: ooh i get it: why is it asking you a 'misha-local' password while you are 'misha'?...yes i really misread the qustion. Means 'misha-local' has higher privileges. Is it a server ubuntu or normal?

Comment: I think you should ask OP (which is not me :))

Comment: It's a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop installation.